# How can a libqt4-gui dependency problem be solved in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, dpkg, dependencies, skype

When I attempt to install Skype Call Recorder on Ubuntu 16.04, I run into dependency problems. The installation procedure I'm using currently is as follows:

```
sudo apt-get -y install libqtgui4
sudo apt-get -y install libid3-tools:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libid3-3.8.3v5:i386
sudo apt-get -y install libid3-tools
sudo apt-get -y install libid3-3.8.3v5
wget http://atdot.ch/scr/files/0.10/skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.10_amd64.deb
sudo su -c 'DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.10_amd64.deb'
```

When I attempt to install the program, I am presented with the following terminal output:

```
Selecting previously unselected package skype-call-recorder.
(Reading database ... 485056 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack skype-call-recorder-ubuntu_0.10_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking skype-call-recorder (0.10) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of skype-call-recorder:
 skype-call-recorder depends on libqt4-gui (>= 4.3); however:
  Package libqt4-gui is not installed.
 skype-call-recorder depends on libid3-3.8.3c2a; however:
  Package libid3-3.8.3c2a is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package skype-call-recorder (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 skype-call-recorder
```

What should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Did you try to install it?

Comment: @GunnarHjalmarsson How do you mean? My question mentions that I attempted to install it and describes the procedure I used to attempt to install it.

Comment: I meant: `sudo apt install libqt4-gui libid3-3.8.3c2a`

Comment: Have the same problem. The packages are not available (anymore) neither in 16.04, nor in 18.04. What is the alternative?